RollupError: A polyfill is required for one or more node builtins
//this is my roolup comnfig file and i am getting error RollupError: A polyfill is required for one or more node builtins while building the app. app contains nextjs, styped component, css modules, typescript
import fs from 'node:fs';
import { createModule } from '@vp/ubik-rollup';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));

const packageName = pkg.name;
const external = [...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies ?? {})];

export default [
    // Multiple output formats (esm, system, cjs) and types for web target
    createModule({
        input: './src/web/index.tsx',
        packageName,
        external,
        platform: 'web',
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.web.json',
        format: 'systemjs',
        plugins: [
            nodePolyfills()
        ]
    }),
    // Multiple output formats (esm, system, cjs) and types for node target
    createModule({
        input: './src/node/index.tsx',
        packageName,
        external,
        platform: 'node',
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.node.json',
        format: 'systemjs',
        plugins: [
            nodePolyfills()
        ]
    }),
];

